# Installation never finishes on an old Dell Latitude C400

Tags: 12.04, installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on an old Dell Latitude C400 laptop previously running windows XP using an Ubuntu install CD.
The OS runs fine off the CD if a bit slow, and the installation starts off fine. However once the progress bar is filled I get put back to the desktop and nothing happens, first I assumed that the installation was completed but when I restarted the computer and booted from the hard drive nothing happened.
I tried to install a few more times but the same thing happens.

Am I doing something wrong? I do not get a error message or a installation complete notification.
Is there any way I could get some kind of debug screen or log to see if something went wrong or at least follow the installation progress in more detail.

Comment: How much RAM memory have you got? All my Dell C400s are maxed out to 1Gb each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to install from the desktop, boot from CD and choose install rather than try Ubuntu. From there you can install the OS without even needing to go to the desktop.

**EDIT: Beat me to the answer ha. Like frantique said you could try the text install. Or go ahead and try what i said above.**

Comment: Thanks for the tip, when I used the direct install I got an error message before it sent me to the desktop.
it said "Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error" and gave me an executable path.

Comment: Did you check the MD5 sum of your ISO to make sure it wasnt corrupt before you burned it to disc?

Answer (score 1):

The Dell Latitude C400 is a little bit old... Try to install from alternate cd [download from here](http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso), this is a text based installer.

> The text-based installer is for computers that can’t run the graphical
>   interface-based installer, either because they don’t meet the minimum
>   requirements for the live CD or because they require extra
>   configuration before the graphical desktop can be used.

Comment: Thanks I am going to try it using the text installer now.